# Animation not play with UIIView subClass (DrawRect method)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview, drawrect

I have a view with a Tap gesture recognizer. When I touch it, there is an animation which modify the background color. My problem is that when i subclass my view to override the drawRect method my animation doesn't play anymore...
How i can fixe this ?
Sorry for my english and thank by advance =)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
  {

    [super drawRect:rect];

    NSLog(@"DrawRect test");
    //H Black line
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGFloat black[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, black);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 319.0f, 0.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 319.0f, 55.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);

    //H White Line
    c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGFloat white[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, white);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 320.0f, 1.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);

    //V White Line
    c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, black);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 0.0f, 54.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 320.0f, 54.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);
}
```

And my Animation :

```
 //Debut
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
        [self.foreView setBackgroundColor:RGBA(RED_CELL, GREEN_CELL, BLUE_CELL, 0.6f)];
    }];
}

//Fin
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        [self.foreView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }];
}
```

How my subview is Added

```
    //foreView
    _foreView  = [[ForeViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 55)];
    [self.foreView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.foreView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.foreView];
```

Comment: Show some code please. Did you called super's drawRect method ?

Comment: Yes I call the super Draw rect, my code is really simple I'll add it in the question.

Comment: Can you show how you initialize your subview and add it to the viewcontroller ? is it done manually ?

Comment: It's added to the question.

Comment: I add it in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: Yeah I did not refresh it :)

Comment: How is _foreView synthesized ?

Comment: I think the problem is not here because when i remove my DrawRect Method it's work ,my animation play...

Comment: I mean do you use an alias in the synthesize syntax like synthesize foreView = _forView ?

Comment: Xcode do it automatically now, so Yes !

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
[self.foreView setBackgroundColor:RGBA(RED_CELL, GREEN_CELL, BLUE_CELL, 0.6f)];
[self.foreView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

to

```
[self.foreView.layer setBackgroundColor:[RGBA(RED_CELL, GREEN_CELL, BLUE_CELL, 0.6f) CGColor]];
[self.foreView.layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
```